# Select change event issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My issue is that the `change` event will trigger whenever there is a change made in `select` element which also includes the page load when select element is populated with items and I don't want this.

I only want the `change` event (or some more proper event) to trigger ONLY when a selection is changed by the user via the mouse or keyboard.

In WPF this is resolved by having `change` and `selectionchange` events which correspond to the second scenario that I want.

```
<select id="filter_notification_byproductname" name="filter_notification_byproductname" asp-for="@Model.FilterByProductName" class="notification_list_list_filter_controll_input" asp-items="@Model.ProductDictionaryOfSelectListItemsForFiltering.Keys" multiple></select>
```

```html
@section Scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#filter_notification_byproductname").bind("change", {
        productChanged: true
      }, SendIndexes);

      function SendIndexes(productChanged) {
        // SEND DATA TO THE SERVER
      }
    }
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: @isherwood I think I did. Simple problem is described very clear

Comment: Don't add the event to the select until it is populated (use `addEventListener` instead on `onchange`). If you want better advice, provide more detail (preferably with code)...

Comment: `I only want 'change' event (or some more proper event) to trigger ONLY when selection is changed by user via mouse or keyboard.` This is already how the `change` event works. If you're seeing the `change` event occur without user interaction, then somewhere in your code is programmatically triggering the event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please see the simplified code sample

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but my previous comment applies there - the event will only be fired when the user interacts with the `#filter_notification_byproductname` element, or your code programmatically raises an event on that element. Also, note that `bind()` is a *very* outdated method and was removed from jQuery quite some time ago. I'd suggest updating the version you're using. For reference, the latest version at time of this comment is 3.6.0

Comment: Given that we know how a `select` `change` event works (and it's not how you've described but as described by @RoryMcCrossan above), you'll need to provide a *complete* snippet, including HTML (see [mcve]) that *demonstrates* the problem you've described.  It's trivial to show that the event doesn't fire: https://jsfiddle.net/k7no81w0/

Comment: [`selectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/selectionchange_event) event involves the selection of text in an `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

Comment: *includes the page load when select element is populated with items* - does the code that adds the `option`s also call `.change()` event?  not binding, something like  `$("#filter_notification_byproductname").change()`

Comment: @freedomn-m no, but this select element gets loaded with data from server on page load. I just included this line in code sample. so my guess is that this load is considered as 'change' and that's why it gets triggered

Comment: Adding new `option`s also doesn't trigger the event.  https://jsfiddle.net/k7no81w0/1/   I suggest you narrow down the exact line that's triggering the event.

Comment: *select element gets loaded with data from server on page load* - can you provide the code that does this load (not the server-side code).   Are you using a third-party drop down such as [tag:select2]?

Comment: @freedomn-m I already did...asp-items="@Model.ProductDictionaryOfSelectListItemsForFiltering.Keys"...and asp-for="@Model.FilterByProductName" is what sets the index to some value that came from the server...so I think this is the point where the change index is made

Comment: Wrap `$("#filter_notification_byproductname").bind("change", {` inside doc.ready `$(document).ready(() => { $("#filter_notification_byproductname").bind("change", {...`

Comment: Ok, that's just a confusion on what "page load" means - server-side code is run on *page render* so will already be set in the HTML before the javascript runs.   But I may be mistaken with [tag:asp.net-core].

Comment: @freedomn-m I just did, but it didn't help